# Get sid from event and convert it back to username

Tags: event-log, sid, get-winevent

I try to use command below to get user sid from a specific event, convert it to username and after that put to output its value.

```
$sid = Get-Winevent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='system';ID=1065} -MaxEvents 1 | Select User -ExpandProperty Userid
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ($sid)
$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objUser.Value
```

I couldn't find the reason why it isn't working. It can't decode username.
`$objUser` should store the username for the SID. I try to use it for domain users. SID should be valid, because I get it from an existing event.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe : Sorry, I edited question, but don't know what exactly this problem is caused by.

Comment: What's in `$objUser`? What were you expecting? Are you sure that the SID actually maps to a user? Is this a domain user, or a local user? Does it fail for all SIDs, or just for some of them? Is it reporting an exception?